# Getting Null array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have following code :

```
- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender 
{

    if(buttonCount==0)
    {
        previousStateArray=setUpArray;
          NSLog(@"previous array count=%d",[previousStateArray count]);
        [setUpArray removeAllObjects];
        for(Node *n in nodeArray)
        {
            if(![temp isEqualToString:n.strName])
            {
                [setUpArray addObject:n.strName];

            }
            temp=n.strName;         
        }    
    }
}  

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender 
{

    [setUpArray removeAllObjects];
    setUpArray=previousStateArray;
     NSLog(@"previous array count=%d",[previousStateArray count]);
    buttonCount--;       
  }
```

Both setUpArray and previousStateArray are declared in the -`viewDidLoad` method.My view is loading only once.In first NSLog i am getting 1 as a output but in second NSLog i am getting

0 as a output while none of my array initialize again . so why this is happening???

Comment: which array count is 1 and u get zero? previous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your array pointers.

In `goButton` :

```
previousStateArray=setUpArray;
```

Now `previousStateArray` points to the same array `setUpArray` is pointing to.

```
[setUpArray removeAllObjects];
```

This removes all objects and now both pointers point to an empty array.

In `backButton`:

```
setUpArray=previousStateArray;
```

They both point to the same empty array so this line is redundant. 
You should keep a temporary pointer if you want to swap the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
`previousStateArray=setUpArray;`  //previousStateArray pointing to same memory location of setUpArray.
```

Use `- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)otherArray` method of `NSMutableArray` class.

```
[previousStateArray setArray: setUpArray];
[setUpArray setArray:previousStateArray];  

- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender 
{

    if(buttonCount==0)
    {
        [previousStateArray setArray: setUpArray];
          NSLog(@"previous array count=%d",[previousStateArray count]);
        [setUpArray removeAllObjects];
        for(Node *n in nodeArray)
        {
            if(![temp isEqualToString:n.strName])
            {
                [setUpArray addObject:n.strName];

            }
            temp=n.strName;         
        }    
    }
}  

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender 
{

    [setUpArray removeAllObjects];
    [setUpArray setArray:previousStateArray];
     NSLog(@"previous array count=%d",[previousStateArray count]);
    buttonCount--;       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array

```
setUpArray = [[NSMuatableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think giorashc's answer is correct. 
Your problem is using "=" for Array only makes the new one previousStateArray points to the same memory of setUpArray. In other words, previousStateArray is the same as setUpArray .

For more detail information , you should search deep & shallow copy.

Answer (score -1):

You should also use `if(0 == buttonCount)` rather than `if(buttonCount==0)`.